# Example of a filter on a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Just wanted to double check my understanding of filters and ultrafilters. I'm trying to come up with some concrete examples on finite sets first of all.

Let S={3,4,5}. Then P(S)={{},{3},{4},{5},{3,4},{3,5},{4,5},{3,4,5}}. Now if we were to order S under set inclusion it will form a poset i.e. (P(S), set inclusion) is a poset. Then if we define F={{3},{3,4},{3,5},{3,4,5}} this will form a filter: F is obviously non-empty. If we pick any two sets from F then their intersection is in F. and supersets are in F, (if we pick an element from it). Is this correct so far? I think that S is actually a principal ultrafilter?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your $F$ is the principal ultrafilter centered on $3$; it consists of all the subsets of $S$ that contain $3$.

All ultrafilters on a *finite* set are principal, so thinking too much about about the finite case may not give you a lot of insight about non-principal ultrafilters.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I've thought alot more about the non-principal case, but was trying to get an idea of what these filters etc actually look like; difficult in infinite case. Okay so need a set to be infinite to be a non-principal ultrafilter, and it will only be non-principal iff it contains the Frechet filter (since if we take complements of an infinite set, we get only finite elements).

Comment: Perhaps the easiest nontrivial i.e. nonprincipal filter to think about next is the *cofinite* filter, alias the *Frechet* filter, on $\mathbb{N}$. It's the set of all complements of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ i.e. $\{X \subseteq \mathbb{N} \mid (\mathbb{N} \setminus X) \; is \; finite \}$. A subset $X \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is in the cofinite filter *iff* for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $X \supseteq \{k \in \mathbb{N} \mid k \ge n\}$, i.e. X contains a final segment of the integers, every integer from "some point ($n$) on".